# ros2 DDS compilation with libc 2.19

Tags: ros, ros2, dds

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

We tried compiling ros2  on our pretty old system running [debian8 Jessie](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianJessie#Architectures) with  libc: libc6 **2.19-18** . It appears that eProsima Fast RTPS (rmw_fastrtps_cpp) requires libc atleast 2.5. Wondering if any other implements out there such as RTI Connext etc. has such required OR In simpler terms,  is there any other DDS implementation out there that can be compile on libc 2.19

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/340429/ros2-dds-compilation-with-libc-2.19/) by [BhanuKiran.Chaluvadi](https://answers.ros.org/users/28829/bhanukiran.chaluvadi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 241 on 2019-12-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is problem was with my SDK, the way i prepared it. After fixing it, I am managed to cross compile minimal-cpp-example with default DDS implementation provided.

---

Originally posted by [BhanuKiran.Chaluvadi](https://answers.ros.org/users/28829/bhanukiran.chaluvadi/) with karma: 241 on 2020-02-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0